# Android: When app is on background.I want to pass a static value (1) to TotalRoomActivity activity on notification click?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

eg: details about the question...I want to pass a value (1) to TotalRoomActivity on notification click when app is on background.i've implemented it but data showing null in TotalRoomActivity .Its working fine when app is open. but not working when is in backgroundBelow i've mentioned the code please find and check that.

### MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public static final String FCM_PARAM = "image";
private static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "FCM";
private static final String CHANNEL_DESC = "Firebase Cloud Messaging";
private int numMessages = 0;
String push_message="1";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

  /*  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mindemo);
    mediaPlayer.start();*/

    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

    sendNotification(notification, data);

    String click_action_data = remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action");
    Intent intent = new Intent(click_action_data);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification, Map<String, String> data) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(FCM_PARAM, data.get(FCM_PARAM));

    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(this, TotalRoomActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("push_message",push_message);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.notification_channel_id))
            .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
            .setContentText(notification.getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(sound)
            //.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bubble))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentInfo("Doale")
            //.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.doaleblacklogo))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(notification.getBody()))
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 300)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setNumber(++numMessages)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.doaleblacklogo);

    Intent result_Intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TotalRoomActivity.class);
    result_Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    try {
        String picture = data.get(FCM_PARAM);
        if (picture != null && !"".equals(picture)) {
            URL url = new URL(picture);
            Bitmap bigPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(
                    new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bigPicture).setSummaryText(notification.getBody())
            );
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                getString(R.string.notification_channel_id), CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
        channel.setDescription(CHANNEL_DESC);
        channel.setShowBadge(true);
        channel.canShowBadge();
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500});
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

### FirebaseBackgroundService :

public class FirebaseBackgroundService extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

```
private static final String TAG = "FirebaseService";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "I'm in!!!");

    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
        for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet()) {
            Object value = intent.getExtras().get(key);
            Log.e("FirebaseDataReceiver", "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
            if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("gcm.notification.body") && value != null) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                Intent backgroundIntent = new Intent(context, TotalRoomActivity.class);
                backgroundIntent.putExtra("push_message", "1");
                backgroundIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                context.startService(backgroundIntent);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

### TotalRoomActivity :

```
public class TotalRoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView room_recycleview;

ArrayList<Integer> room_list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> room_number_list = new ArrayList<>();
String getstatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_room_total);

    if (getstatus==null){
        getstatus="";
    }

    getstatus = getIntent().getStringExtra("push_message");

    Toast.makeText(this, getstatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    });

    room_recycleview = findViewById(R.id.room_recycleview);

    room_recycleview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    room_recycleview.hasFixedSize();
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(TotalRoomActivity.this, 2);
    room_recycleview.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    ItemOffsetDecoration itemDecoration = new ItemOffsetDecoration(TotalRoomActivity.this, R.dimen.item_offset);
    room_recycleview.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
    room_recycleview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);


    room_list.add(R.drawable.roomonee);
    room_list.add(R.drawable.roomtwoo);
    room_list.add(R.drawable.roomthreee);
    room_list.add(R.drawable.roomfourr);
    room_list.add(R.drawable.rooomfivee);
    room_list.add(R.drawable.roomsixx);

    room_number_list.add("R1");
    room_number_list.add("R2");
    room_number_list.add("R3");
    room_number_list.add("R4");
    room_number_list.add("R5");
    room_number_list.add("R6");

    RoomAdapter roomAdapter = new RoomAdapter(TotalRoomActivity.this, room_list,room_number_list);
    room_recycleview.setAdapter(roomAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_right, R.anim.slide_to_left);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the intent data on the "onResume" method of TotalRoomActivity? Sometimes if the activity is initiated and in background, if you click on the notification the onReceive method is not activated, but the App still collects the info on the intent.

Comment: Ok Thankx. i'll try